# Archive files with GNU tar after removing leading directory path

Tags: tar

I would like to flatten and archive the following structure:

```
├── a
│   └── a.txt
├── ...
│   └── ...
└── z
    └── z.txt
```

in this tar archive:

```
a.txt
...
z.txt
```

I could, for example,

1. flatten the structure in some temporary location with `cp` and then archive
2. create the archive iteratively (tar option `--append`) and use `--directory` each time
3. flatten the structure at extraction time with `--strip-components`

Any other smart idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out about `--transform`:

```
 File name transformations:

      --strip-components=NUMBER   strip NUMBER leading components from file
                             names on extraction
      --transform=EXPRESSION, --xform=EXPRESSION
                             use sed replace EXPRESSION to transform file
                             names
```

Lovely:

```
tar -caf archive.tar.xz --transform 's|.*/\(.*\)|\1|g' $(find . -type f)
```

Comment: Better as `find . -type f -print0 | tar --null -T - --transform='s|.*/||' -caf archive.tar.xz`. That `$(find . -type f)` only works correctly if file paths don't contain characters of IFS nor wildcards nor backslash and the list is not too big. Note that you need the GNU implementation of `tar` for `--transform` (and that `-a`).

Answer (score -1):

I'd untar everything into a directory, and use `rsync` to put everything into one directory, and tar it up again.